# Как подключаться к серверу с помощью RCON?

Tags: java, steam

Ищу подходящую библиотеку для подключения к серверу, но все они ужасны или не работают (Запрос отправляется, а ответа нету). Подскажите подходящую для Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я писал бота для игры [Squad](http://joinsquad.com) и тоже столкнулся с такой же проблемой.

Проанализировав отправку и прием пакетов, я заметил, что сервер передавал мне несколько пакетов (хотя RCON отправляет только один обычно) и моя программа, использующая библиотеку [rkon-core](https://github.com/Kronos666/rkon-core) улавливала только первый пакет (из 3), а другие игнорировала. Я уверен, что у Вас такая же проблема

Поискав в интернете разные библиотеки, я наткнулся на [steam-condenser](https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser) (Подходит для **PHP, Java и Ruby**). Она не только подключается по RCON к серверу, но и делает steam query запросы (чтобы получать данные с сервера, не имея доступа к нему).

Для Java вот ссылка на эту библиотеку:
https://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser-java

Пример **подлючения по RCON**:

```java
InetAddress serverIp = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
SourceServer server = new SourceServer(serverIp);
try {
  server.rconAuth("passw0rd");
  System.out.println(server.rconExec("status"));
}
catch(RCONNoAuthException e) {
  System.err.println("Could not authenticate with the game server.");
}
```

Пример **Querying game servers:**

```java
InetAddress serverIp = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.114");
GoldSrcServer server = new GoldSrcServer(serverIp, 27016);
server.initialize();
System.out.println(server.getServerInfo());
```